# C++ Format for cout << Automatically

Tags: c++, cout

If I had a simple class with two variables, x and y, and a function ToString() that returns a formatted string with the data. When I call

```
cout << simpleClass << "\n";
```

anyone know a way I could have simpleClass.ToString automatically called to return the correctly formatted string? I'm guessing there's a way to do this with operator functions, but I don't know how I would do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're asking how to define such an operator,

```cpp
template<class CharT, class TraitsT>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>&
operator <<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, TraitsT>& os, SimpleClass const& sc)
{
    return os << sc.ToString();
}
```

Comment: +1: I like how you implemented a function which operates on all `basic_ostream` objects, not just `cout`

Comment: @ildjarn: However, I wonder how you are going to write a `SimpleClass::ToString()` member that would return any string requested. (Am I missing something?)

Comment: @sbi : The assumption is that the user will pass in a stream compatible with the character-type of the string, otherwise there will be a compiler error (just like trying to stream a `std::wstring` to a `std::ostream`).

Comment: @ildjarn: My point is that in this case it makes no sense to templatify the output operator, because, thanks to the non-template member function `ToString()`, it would require a truly convoluted hack for this to compile with any character encoding but one.

Comment: @sbi : And I fully disagree -- there's more to a stream/string type than just the character type; e.g.  the stream could use a non-default `TraitsT` argument.

Comment: @ildjarn: You are right, of course, I overlooked that. OTOH, it should not be templatized on the character type, when there is support only for one character type.

Comment: @sbi : I disagree with that as well; `char const*` and `std::string` both stream equally well to `std::basic_ostream<char>` and `std::basic_ostream<wchar_t>` (e.g. `std::cout` and `std::wcout`). Why should I be forced to use a narrow stream just because the character type is narrow?

Comment: @ildjarn: I actually had to check that `std::wcout << "Hello, world!\n"` compiles. I didn't know! Well, since that's really compiles, there's indeed merit in your code, and I just failed to see this. I apologize, but I honestly didn't know you can pass a narrow string to a wide stream. How do we proceed? Shall I delete my useless comments and you then delete yours?

Comment: @sbi : I think the comments could be edifying for future readers, but it's up to you. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn: Ok, so I'll leave it.

Answer (score 2):

You define

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream&, const SimpleClass&)
```

to call `ToString()`, passing the `ostream&`, and return the `ostream&`.